# The content of element type "servlet" must match "(icon?,servlet-name,display-name?,

Tags: java, servlets, web

i know is about the order but i tried already all the posibilities,
if it is someone that can explain me the order for my web.xml file?
thanks.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd">

<web-app>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.ewheelz.SessionCounter</listener-class>
    </listener>
  <servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ConnectionPool</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ewheelz.ConnectionPool</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ConnectionPool</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/servlet/ConnectionPool</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>Home.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

</web-app>
```

Comment: Did you check your linked [DTD](http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change this**

```
<servlet>
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
    <servlet-name>ConnectionPool</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.ewheelz.ConnectionPool</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
```

**to this:-**

```
  <servlet>    
    <servlet-name>ConnectionPool</servlet-name>
    <display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name> 
    <description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
    <servlet-class>com.ewheelz.ConnectionPool</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
```

**`diplay-name and description tag should come after servlet-name tag`**

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by configuring servlet and servlet-mapping by using design view in eclipse instead of typing directly in the web.xml in source view. Hope this helps.